# spring jms listener consumer size doesn't go down

Tags: spring, jms, listener, limit

[image]I have below spring jms listener configuration to handle large number of messages. when there are more than 200 message arrives, it's able to process all message w/o any error and while looking at JMX console, it shows around 13560 consumer active to process message. However after all messages are handled (i.e.processing is done), the number of consumer doesn't go down, it shows same number.  Can someone tell me what could be the reason? Am i missing any configuration or code?

```
<bean id="jndiTemplate" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate">
        <property name="environment">
            <props>
                <prop key="java.naming.factory.initial">org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory</prop>
                <prop key="java.naming.provider.url">${PROVIDER.URL}</prop>
                <prop key="java.naming.factory.url.pkgs">org.jboss.naming:org.jnp.interfaces</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="connectionFactory" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
        <property name="jndiTemplate" ref="jndiTemplate" />
        <property name="jndiName" value="/ConnectionFactory" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="jmsQueueConnectionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.jms.connection.CachingConnectionFactory" >
        <property name="targetConnectionFactory">
            <ref bean="connectionFactory" />
        </property>
        <property name="sessionCacheSize" value="5"/>
        <!--  <property name="reconnectOnException" value="true" /> -->
    </bean>



    <bean id="jmsDestinationResolver"
        class="org.springframework.jms.support.destination.JndiDestinationResolver">
        <property name="jndiTemplate" ref="jndiTemplate" />
        <property name="cache" value="true" />
    </bean>

    <jms:listener-container connection-factory="jmsQueueConnectionFactory"
            destination-type="queue" 
            destination-resolver="jmsDestinationResolver" 
            error-handler="errorHandler"
            acknowledge="auto"
            concurrency="10-50"
            cache="consumer">
            <jms:listener destination="${REMOTE.REQUEST.QUEUE}"
                ref="reportGenerationMessageDelegate"
                selector="messageType = '${PDF.REPORT.MESSAGE.TYPE}' OR 
                          messageType = '${CSV.REPORT.MESSAGE.TYPE}'" />
        </jms:listener-container>
```

So current design is as below:
1. i have Jboss esb service class, which sends message on RequestQueue and waiting for response on ResponseQueue. Here is configuration of the class

```
<bean id="jndiTemplate" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate">
    <property name="environment">
        <props>
            <prop key="java.naming.factory.initial">org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory</prop>
            <prop key="java.naming.provider.url">${JMS.server.URL}</prop>
            <prop key="java.naming.factory.url.pkgs">org.jboss.naming:org.jnp.interfaces</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="connectionFactory" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
    <property name="jndiTemplate" ref="jndiTemplate" />
    <property name="jndiName" value="/ConnectionFactory" />
</bean>

<bean id="jmsDestinationResolver"
    class="org.springframework.jms.support.destination.JndiDestinationResolver">
    <property name="jndiTemplate" ref="jndiTemplate" />
</bean>

<bean id="jmsTemplate" class="org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate">
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="connectionFactory" />
    <property name="destinationResolver" ref="jmsDestinationResolver" />
</bean>
```

The listener class config is as below:

SOAReportGenreation class extends AbstractRemoteRequestListener class which receives message

```
    public abstract class AbstractRemoteRequestListener {

        /**
     * Method processMessage.
     * @param message ObjectMessage
     * @return String
     * @throws JMSException
     * @throws Exception
     */
    public abstract String processMessage(ObjectMessage message) throws JMSException, Exception;

    /**
     * Method handleMessage.
     * @param message ObjectMessage
     * @return String
     * @throws JMSException
     * @throws Exception
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public String consumeMessage(ObjectMessage message) throws JMSException, Exception{
      try {
        if (message != null) {
            l.info("Message received for messageType= "+ message.getStringProperty("messageType"));
            Map<String, Object> map = (HashMap<String, Object>) message.getObject();
            return processMessage(message);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        L.error(e);
}
      return null;
    }
}
```

### SOAReportGeneration.java

```
public class SOAReportGeneration extends AbstractRemoteRequestListener{
    private static final Logger L = Logger.getLogger(SOAReportGeneration.class);
    private static ApplicationContext context;

    @Override
    public String processMessage(ObjectMessage message) throws JMSException, Exception {
        if(context == null){
            context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("serviceContext.xml");
        }else{
            L.info("using already initialized spring context");
        }
        //business logic. i am loading service context to get bean definition
        //and instantiate certain beans for business processing.
        return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you really mean 13560 consumers? I hope it is a typo.

In order to answer your question, [Spring JMS doc](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/jms.html) clearly states that the specified minimum number of consumers may be ignored at runtime. See below:

> The number of concurrent sessions/consumers to start for each listener. Can either be a simple number indicating the maximum number (e.g. "5") or a range indicating the lower as well as the upper limit (e.g. "3-5"). **Note that a specified minimum is just a hint and might be ignored at runtime**. Default is 1; keep concurrency limited to 1 in case of a topic listener or if queue ordering is important; consider raising it for general queues.

Comment: Edited my answer with number of consumers showing in JMX Console. This number is when there was around 300 messages i dropped at same time to process. But still number is large. don't know how to ensure that it limits number of consumers.

Comment: This does not really make sense. Since your spring configuration states max concurrent consumers to be 50; no matter how many messages you put on that queue; number of consumers associated to that queue should not surpass 50. Are you sure you are looking at the right thing(Number of consumers listening to this particular queue)?

If yes, I would be curious to see the behavior by using PooledConnectionFactory instead of CachingConnectionFactory.

Comment: I am not using ActiveMQ. i am using Jboss server and it uses HornetQ, i didn't find PooledConnectionFactory for HornetQ. I got this number from JMX Console, as shown in image. I edited my question with more details, if that can help.

Comment: I understand. Can you try spring's SingleConnectionFactory instead then? It would result in a lot of IO overhead but it would be good to rule out the possibility of this issue being caused by the use of CachingConnectionFactory. Also, are we talking about a single instance of consumer application listening to this queue or are there multiple instances invloved listening to the same broker queue?

Comment: i have already tried with SingleConnectionFactory but don't see any change.  So consumer application is another application (ESB) which has client.jar file (i.e. client jar has listener class) and currently deployed on same server as Producer (ESB), but we can deploy to other server also. So instance wise, i would think, it's single instance of consumer application.

Comment: I think it would be worth it to deploy the consumer application to another server outside ESB to rule out the possibility of ESB causing the issue.

Comment: I can try that on higher environment because dont have setup on local. However i dont understand how esb is causing this issue? I am using MessageListenerAdapter, is that causing issue? Was thinking to change it to basic JMS implementation